# Регулярное выражение для форматированного целого или дробного числа с одним или двумя знаками в дробной части

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно регулярное выражение для дробного числа.
Чтобы выражение пропускало числа, запятые и от 0 до 1 точки. Если присутствует точка, то чтобы после неё было от 1 до 2 чисел.

Примеры в каком виде числа должны проходить:

```
241
3,423.1
324.34
342,333.33
```

Примеры в каком виде числа НЕ должны проходить:

```
23423.
42.343.33
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/4YACPy/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `\d{1,3}` - 1, 2 или 3 цифры
- `(?:,\d{3})*` - 0 и более повторов последовательностей: `,` и три цифры (`\d{3}`)
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - 1 или 0 повторов точки (`\.`) и одной или двух цифр (`\d{1,2}`)
- `$` - конец строки.

Демо-код:

```js
var strs = ['241','3,423.1','324.34','342,333.33','23423.','42.343.33'];
var rx = /^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```

#### Если вы хотите пропустить все строки типа `01.2`, `002`, используйте

```
^(?!0+[1-9])\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Негативный блок предварительного просмотра вперёд `(?!0+[1-9])` не найдет совпадения, если строка начинается с 1+ нуля и потом за ними следует цифра, отличная от нуля.

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/4YACPy/2).

Comment: успешно проходит `001`, хотя не должно

Comment: @Lexx918 Этого условия нет в задаче, но я добавил решение, также удовлетворяющее вашему условию.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, как прочитать выражения '?!0+' и '?:,' ? Такие конструкции встречаю впервые.

Comment: @Kosmos `(?!0+[1-9])` — негативный (отрицающий) блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, индекс движка регулярных выражений остаётся где был, проверяется идущий непосредственно после текущей позиции текст на совпадение шаблона данного блока, и если совпадение найдено, совпадение считается ненайденным. `(?:...)` — незахватывающая группа, служит только для группировки подшаблонов/символов.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, не знал, спасибо. Есть ссылка, где можно почитать про это подробнее?

Comment: См. [тут](https://habr.com/post/115436/), и [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#noncapturing_group), и [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zerowidth_negative_lookbehind_assertion).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, благодарю)

Comment: @Kosmos Снова я перепутал проверку вперёд и назад :) Вот [тут описана конструкция `(?!...)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zero-width-negative-lookahead-assertions).

Answer (score 0):

Держи `^[\d]+((,[\d]+|)*(\.[\d]{1,2})|)$`

[image: пруф]

Comment: успешно проходит `001`, хотя не должно. и зачем квадратные скобки везде вокруг `\d`?

Comment: @Lexx918 Этого условия нет в задаче.

Comment: да, квадратные скобки можно опустить - это я по привычке... :))

Answer (score 0):

[Например](https://regex101.com/r/980qz5/3), так:

```
^([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*|0)(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Comment: [Ваше выражение не найдет `0.01`](https://regex101.com/r/980qz5/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew точно. спасибо, поправил